# what when displaying a variable with kint crashes?

Tags: 8, theming, debugging

I am trying to find the variable name for the content link in a view.

`{{ kint(content) }}` makes the page crash, probably because the variable is too big.

The same is true for the following code.

```
function my_theme_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
    var_dump($variables);
}
```

How can I find out what I am looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually D8 $variables contain way too much data, and browser struggle to render it for you.
I strongly suggest to use xdebug or similar debugger, all modern IDEs support it. It makes developer's life much easier.
However, there is a workaround without having xdebug configured:

```
function my_theme_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
    var_dump(array_keys($variables));
    // or better:
    kint(array_keys($variables));
    // or:
    dpm(array_keys($variables));
}
```

This will return you top-level keys, then you can drill down to the next level:

```
dpm(array_keys($variables['some_key']));
```

For objects use type casting:

```
dpm((array) array_keys($object));
```

Set Kint as Variables Dumper on /admin/config/development/devel (with Devel Kint module enabled) and you'll get nicely structured output.

In Twig templates you can use something like this:

```
{% for key, value in content %}
    {{ key }}
{% endfor %}
```

UPD: Valuable comment from [Kevin](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/45773/kevin) for TWIG:

```
{{ kint(content|keys) }}
```

Comment: in twig template you can use {{ kint(content|keys }}